# text input not binding to object array

Tags: angularjs

Upon initial rendering the data shows up fine, meaning if I have data for the custom fields the values are displayed on the HTML.

The problem is when I change the values of the custom fields, the changes are not attached back to the object, in other words it appears the binding is only one way for some reason.

I have the following object:

```
{ 
        "_id" : BinData(3, "6aUPCzvqTUuzZWlWRJCdPQ=="), 
        "name" : "MyObject", 
        "customFields" : [
            {
                "_id" : BinData(3, "ksRiQNZnuE2BKFpjbQEQaQ=="), 
                "name" : "Field 1", 
                "order" : NumberInt(1), 
                "type" : "string", 
                "isMultiValue" : false, 
                "values" : [
                    "11111"
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : BinData(3, "S9bSzoqy5EafPP0NEdbfCw=="), 
                "name" : "Field 2", 
                "order" : NumberInt(2), 
                "type" : "string", 
                "isMultiValue" : false, 
                "values" : [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I have the following HTML bound to it:

```
                    <div ng-repeat="customField in customer.customFields">
                        <p>
                            {{customField.name}}:
                        </p>
                        <p ng-repeat="customFieldValue in customField.values">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="customFieldValue" />
                        </p>
                    </div>
```

Update:
After the suggestion from @ngLover I got the binding to work correctly in this case:

Here is the new object:

```
{ 
    "_id" : BinData(3, "FKibZl5WDk2jprg1gY5KAQ=="), 
    "name" : "MyObject", 
    "customFields" : [
        {
            "_id" : BinData(3, "3HUUHy1FMUaxD41JcuYqQw=="), 
            "name" : "Field 1", 
            "order" : NumberInt(1), 
            "type" : "string", 
            "isMultiValue" : false, 
            "values" : [
                {
                    "value" : "Data 1"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : BinData(3, "2t0oiy5LukSSuPR9XYKwcA=="), 
            "name" : "Field 2", 
            "order" : NumberInt(2), 
            "type" : "string", 
            "isMultiValue" : false, 
            "values" : [
                {
                    "value" : "Data 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

New HTML:

```
                  <div ng-repeat="customField in customer.customFields">
                        <p>
                            {{customField.name}}:
                        </p>
                        <p ng-repeat="customFieldValue in customField.values">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="customFieldValue.value" >
                        </p>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please create fiddle of your code.

Comment: customField.values is an array make it a simple var like values:11111

Comment: @ngLover I changed customField.values to be a custom object and now the binding is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

remember that each `ng-repeat` has its own scope, so, in your second `ng-repeat`, `ng-model="customFieldValue"` is being attached to the second `ng-repeat scope`, not the outer scope.

Comment: child scopes inherit from parent scopes. and you can access parent scope properties using `$scope.$parent.someproperty`